# How to synchronize two asynchronous functions

Tags: swift, delegates, dispatch

I have a delegate which contains the following function:

```
func didFailToConnect(_ interface) {
}
```

and also i have an asynchronous call:

```
   geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in
    
    if error != nil {
     
    }

    if let placemarks = placemarks {
      
    }
  }
```

what i want to achieve is to see if the 2 calls has been finished and inform the user with an alert.Which is the best way to implement this i'm thinking of using DispatchGroup but because the delegate implementation is coming from a third party framework i don't exactly where to put the setup code of dispatch for example:

```
group.enter()
```

and then:

```
func didFailToConnect(_ interface) {
  group.leave()
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: https://agostini.tech/2017/08/20/dispatchgroup-vs-operationqueue-in-swift/

Comment: well, `DispatchGroup` is a great idea ... but I'd need more info regarding your code where you place `didFailToConnect` related to `geocoder.reverse`. I'd need to see more code and where these 2 functions connect